# Extract Unique Keys from an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects which looks like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "a":"alpha",
      "b":{  
         "x":true,
         "y":true
      }
   },
   {  
      "a":"beta",
      "b":{  
         "x":true,
         "z":true
      }
   }
]
```

I want to loop through this array to get a qnique list of all keys of 'b' alone. So, that my resulting array will be:

```
[x,y,z]
```

I tried the following:

```
const mykeys = myArray.map(item => Object.keys(item.b))
```

However, this only gves me: [[x,y], [y,z]]

How can I get the result as [x,y,z] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to concatenate the arrays into single array. Then using [**spread operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) with [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) you can get unique items.

*Set* lets you to store unique values.

```js
const myArray = [  
   {  
      "a":"alpha",
      "b":{  
         "x":true,
         "y":true
      }
   },
   {  
      "a":"beta",
      "b":{  
         "x":true,
         "z":true
      }
   }
]

const mykeys = myArray.map(item => Object.keys(item.b))
                      .reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b));
                      
const uniqueKeys = [...new Set(mykeys)];

console.log(uniqueKeys);
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! I am asusming that this will work, no matter how many objects we have in the initial array. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a dynamic approach by using a variable for the wanted key of the object and get all inner keys.

This approach uses a default object if the given key does not exist.

```js
var data = [{ a: "alpha", b: { x: true, y: true } }, { a: "beta", b: { x: true, z: true } }],
    key = 'b',
    unique = [
        ...new Set(
            data.reduce((r, o) => [...r, ...Object.keys(o[key]) || {}], [])
        )
    ];

console.log(unique);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` with array spread syntax to get the unique keys.

```js
const myArray = [{"a":"alpha","b":{"x":true,"y":true}},{"a":"beta","b":{"x":true,"z":true}}],
      myuniquekeys =[...new Set([].concat(...myArray.map(({b}) => Object.keys(b))))];
      
console.log(myuniquekeys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple and much understanding way to achieve what you want.

```js
var inputArray = [  
   {  
      "a":"alpha",
      "b":{  
         "x":true,
         "y":true
      }
   },
   {  
      "a":"beta",
      "b":{  
         "x":true,
         "z":true
      }
   }
];
var resArray = [];
inputArray.forEach((inputObj)=>{
  var keysForB = Object.keys(inputObj.b);
  keysForB.forEach((keyInB)=>{
    if(!resArray.includes(keyInB)){
       resArray.push(keyInB);
    }
  });
});

console.log(resArray);
```